# Three.js - How to change the Perspective Camera's bending/curve?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, perspectivecamera

I'm using a `Perspective Camera` for my top down Three.js game, but it curves a bit too much because it's designed to be used as "first person view". Is there a way to adjust how much objects bend/curve in the frustum from the sides?

Essentially, I would like something like a mix of a `Perspective Camera` and an `Orthographic Camera`

E.g -- The walls of the buildings should be less visible from a certain distance
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the camera FOV.
https://threejs.org/docs/?q=persp#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera

Made a simple Pen here:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/eYEOqrz

```
camera.fov = 30;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix ();
```

The lesser the FOV, the more flatter things look.
Please note that you'll need to position the camera farther away at lower FOVs to ensure the contents fit inside the view which also requires you to increase the camera's far property so things don't get cut out

Comment: I've tried playing with the `fov` and I thought all it did was zoom in/out. Works, thank you!

Comment: In a way, it is sort of zoom in the sense that it zooms in to narrow down the observable part of the world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view

Comment: Sort of like a `lens`, right?